# Find a string in list of strings, write table in Excel with Datanitro

Tags: excel, datanitro

My worksheet "FX" has 22903 rows and 1 column ("A").

I want to iterate through all lines, find the one that has EC CME EURO FX FUTURES and write the three lines below to row 1, column "B" of the "FX" spread sheet.

I'm using Datanitro and the shell says "You're on 'FX' of 'DailyReport.xlsx'"

I tried:

```
data = Cell("FX","A1").vertical
to_write = []
for i, line in enumerate(data):
    if line.startswith("EC CME EURO FUTURES")
        first_line = i + 1
        break


for i in range (first_line, first_line + 3):
    write_line = line[i]
    write_line = write_line.split("    ")
    to_write.append(data[i])

Cell("B1").table= to_write
```

So, for data that reads "JUN15    1.4612    1.4773B   1.4549A   1.4596A   1.4589  -.0103         533     1.4692         206        1130
" I would get the "J" in one cell, the "U" in another etc. After "5", I would get 4 empty cells and then "1" in the next cell and so on

Comment: Sorry I did not explain very clearly! Mostly I was trying to do all the parsing via Python. Now I have the rows in the columns I want, I can use excel formulas (LEFT, LEN, RIGHT, MID) to get the data

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
data = Cell("A1").vertical # grab the entire column
header_row = data.index("EC CME EURO FX FUTURES")
Cell("B1").vertical = data[header_row + 1: header_row + 4]
```

Comment: Thank you Ben! It works ! I had to modify it a bit because I was getting "list indices must be integers not tuple" error. So I did Cell ("B1").vertical = data[header_row +1]  and Cell("B2").vertical =data[header_row +2], etc. Got 115 points in Codecademy !

Comment: Great! Changed the code to work, had a typo that was causing the error.